# Form Authentication using HTML Client App to ASP.Net Web API (MVC)

Tags: api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I am in a little bit situation now..

I have one web application (HTML, CSS, JS). I have one Log in form there. This is what I need to do.

1. When user enters username and password and Submit Username and Password (string user, string pass) has to be posted in api/authenticate..
2. api/authenticate will check the username and password either in Database / Active Directory.. If the combination is validated the success token will be passed back to web client (HTML app). The success token will be used as authentication flag throughout the application.

I have came across many solutions but couldn't determine which is the best approach to achieve this.

Any solution would be helpful :)

Regards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a `LoginController` in your API that accepts a view model with a `user` and `pass` property.
2. In the login action, you do your username and password lookup against your data store.

   - If the credentials are valid, you generate, store, and return an access token.
   - If the credentials are invalid, your return a HTTP 401 "Unauthorized" error.
3. Serialize your form to JSON and post it to the login endpoint and deal with the response.
4. Store the access token somewhere on the client (e.g. within a cookie or session storage).

Comment: Any best way to generate secure token?

Comment: @RahulPatil `Guid.NewGuid()` should be fine.